# Проверка логического выражения на правильность

Tags: логические-выражения

Допустим есть логическое выражение, которое записано в инфиксной форме.

```
((A or B) and not(C and B))
```

Кроме проверки скобок можно ли еще осуществлять какие-нибудь проверки?

Просто я не знаю будет ли ошибкой записать логическое выражение например так:

```
((A or or B) and not not(C and and B))
```

Если брать арифметические выражения, то например такие записи

`3 - + + - + 3` - не является ошибкой

`3 * * 4` - является ошибкой

`3 * + - + + 4` - не является ошибкой

`3 + * - + - + + 4` - ошибка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как минимум `not not` можно, это [двойное отрицание](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation), так как это унарная операция.

А конъюнкция и дизъюнкция - бинарные операции, которые требуют два операнда, поэтому  нельзя писать `or or` и `and and`.